# filter using custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I am working on a job search page. I have created job category, job location, job description and posted date using Advanced Custom Fields. I want to display the job location and category in a select box and when we click on the search button I have to display all the custom fields based on the selected search. Please help

Comment: You have not provided enough information for us to help you with this.  I recommend looking at WP Job Manager which can handle most of this for you.  You could then use FacetWP or custom code to customize the filtering

Comment: there are two select boxes - job description and job ,location. the values are displaying from custom fields. can you help me in writing custom code to compare job description and job location and display all custom fields that matches the condition